# Bluetooth Atheros AR9462 13d3:3395 cannot detect other devices

Tags: bluetooth

I would like to request assistance getting bluetooth working on two computers. Although I have used Ubuntu for several years now, I have never before submitted a bug report or asked a question on this site, so please forgive my mistakes.

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R with Ubuntu 15.10; kernel 4.2.0-28 generic, and a Dell Inspiron 660 with Ubuntu 14.04; kernel 3.19.0-49. Both were recently upgraded to an Atheros AR9462 WiFi/Bluetooth combo. I have determined that the device ID for both combo modules is `Device ID: 13d3:3395`. I created a bug report that can be referenced at the link below.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1542564

```
lsusb: Bus 003 Device 003: ID 13d3:3395 IMC Networks
hcitool dev: Devices: hci0  6C:71:D9:0D:7D:3A
rfkill list: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So far I have been able to determine that the above listed device ID has not been added to the linux-kernel as it does not appear in the "usb_device_id ath3k_table" or "usb_device_id ath3k_blist_tabl" for either of the previously mentioned kernels.

Please let me know what additional information may be required.

Comment: I will take care of that bug.

Answer (score 0):

I sent a patch upstream. In a while this device will be supported by Ubuntu kernels.

Meanwhile a workaround can be used. Install a dkms package with this patch:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/bluetooth/+files/btusb-lp1542564-dkms_0.2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i btusb-lp1542564-dkms_0.2_all.deb
```

and reboot.

If the bluetooth still does not work, it needs some firmware that is not included in Ubuntu yet. It can be installed by:

```
wget http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2014/01/20623393_919a4673931aa789f0b1c3eeafb360b36097894a.cab
sudo cabextract 20623393_919a4673931aa789f0b1c3eeafb360b36097894a.cab -F *.dfu -d /lib/firmware/ar3k
```

Thanks to Jeremy31 for the link and the command.